# Strip characters from an array before passing to foreach loop

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that creates folders and makes shares based on an array.  So the array is like  `$folders = ("C:\test1", "C:\test2")`

I do a `foreach` loop and make the folders just fine.

Here's the problem.  I want to make another `foreach` loop using the same `$folders` array except strip off the first three characters (so `C:\test1` simply becomes `test1`).  I am doing this to create the shares (which are just the name of the folder without the drive stuff).

How would I strip the first three characters and pass it to my new loop?  Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$newFolders = $folders | % { $_.substring(3) }` will set $newFolders to the array you're looking for.

You can also do it inline with something like `$folders | % { $_.substring(3) } | % { sharing_code }`.

That said, a more robust version would be something like `$newFolders = $folders | % { split-path -leaf $_ }`.

Comment: BOOM - that's what I'm looking for!  The `% { $_.substring(3) }` .  Many thanks.  Very new to Powershell so the syntax is still foreign.

Comment: My third way of doing it (and C.B.'s answer) provide more robust ways methods, btw.

Answer (score 2):

A short solution :)

$folders -replace '^...'

Answer (score 0):

I can think of at least three ways to do that. Pick your favorite ;)

```
# The most basic
$folders | %{$_.trimstart("c:\")}

# This one works with all drive letters
$folders | %{$_ -replace "\w:\\"}

# That last will only return the final file/folder in your path
# If you use a path such as "c:\something\else" then it'll return "else"
$folders | %{split-path $_ -leaf}
```

HTH!

Comment: Oops - never mind.  This works:

`#make folders$folders = ("C:\test\1","C:\test\2")
foreach ($folder in $folders)
 {if(!(Test-Path $folder -PathType Container)){New-Item $folder -type directory}}

#make shares
$shares = $folders | %{split-path $_ -leaf}
foreach ($share in $shares)
 {net share $share=$folder}`